# Integration testing and JNDI resource injection with Weld

Tags: integration-testing, jndi, weld, jboss-weld

I want to test that a DAO/repository works properly with a test database (integration test). In the DAO I inject a JNDI datasource with the resource annotation:

```
public class SomeDAO {

    @Resource(lookup = "java:comp/env/ds")
    private DataSource dataSource;
    ...
}
```

I don't want to use any server during the test, I just want to create a JNDI resource in some way and make Weld discover it and inject it.

Currently I am trying to achieve this using the [Simple-JNDI](https://github.com/h-thurow/Simple-JNDI) library: when I only test that the InitialContext contains the datasource it works, but when I test the DAO, Weld doesn't find the datasource.

How to create JNDI resources for Weld to inject, or how to make it work with Simple-JNDI?

Thanks.

Comment: Just a tiny bit of info about CDI. Being able to `@Inject`/`@Resource` non-CDI beans is (in standard app) a work of the server. It uses Weld SPI to provide information and feed it with classes which will be turned into beans, hence becoming available to CDI. In other words, I think simple-jndi would need to integrate with Weld in order for this to work.

Comment: Or I just need someone to explain how to do the "work of the server" myself in my tests... It's doable with Spring, I wish the Weld developers/community were as resourceful ;-)

Comment: Yea, you might do the work yourself. No need to be arrogant/sarcastic here. Most people coming here wish a complete/easy solution rather than doing it all themselves. I suggest you ask this question on Weld forums where you are guaranteed to get attention from Weld developers/community - https://developer.jboss.org/en/weld